# PHP, как правильно заполнить html таблицу данными из массива

Tags: php

Есть таблица в Google Sheets вида:

Устройство : цена

Я подтягиваю из нее данные в json файл на свой сайт, хочу генерировать из этих значений таблицу у себя на сайте
Получаю массив такого вида `[["Apple","1000"],["Samsung","2200"],["iPhone","3200"],["LG","4500"],["Nokia","4400"]]`

Вывожу так 
`$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('table.json'));`

```
<div class="box">
    <table class="table table-bordered bg-white">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Марка</th>
            <th>Действия</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php foreach ($values as $key => $value): ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?= $key ?></td>      
            </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Не могу понять как мне вывести `["Apple","1000"]` в разные ячейки?
Как правильно написать `foreach` внутри `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждой итерации внутреннего цикла выводите один тег `<td>`:

```php
<?php foreach ($values as $key => $array): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($array as $value): ?>
        <td><?= $value ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Код выдает ошибку Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: [Пример кода](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11cbf960c71e4def1ed18280cbd1ff15dd37b648)

Comment: @ИльяМясников, исправьте в [примере кода](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11cbf960c71e4def1ed18280cbd1ff15dd37b648) `$values = [["Apple","1000"] ...`